# Controle de versão Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, versionamento

Hoje estamos pensando em utilizar um controle de versão de fontes para nosso projetos.

Estamos utilizando o Delphi 7.

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece algum controle de versão de fontes?

Comment: Aqui onde trabalho utilizamos o Tortoise. É gratuito, mas você deve ter uma conta em um repositório, já que ele apenas faz o gerenciamento de subir e baixar os fontes do repositório, gerando revisões de código a cada vez que sobe um fonte novo ou alterado.

Comment: Sugestão de pesquisa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versionamento

Comment: Se vai começar, sugiro usar o Git.
Utilizamos o SVN como ferramenta principal, e ele tem alguns bugs.
O Git funciona diferente do SVN, então dá uma lida no link citado acima das diferenças.